# Ownership of copied files after jenkins job

Tags: linux, deployment, apache2, jenkins

I have a little understanding trouble.

We have a php-website which is build with a jenkins job, after the jenkins build is done the whole website will be copied as tarball to the frontend server and unpack via ssh.

This happens with a seperate user "www-deploy" via ssh and ssh key.

So my problem is now that the ownership of these files are owned by the user "www-deploy" and not apache. I have added this user to the group which runs apache (user:apache/group:apache).

But I don't know if this is the best solution.

1. Is it better to run the apache server under the user "www-deploy"? Especially when the user can login via ssh?
2. Should I change the ownership of the files in the tarball, before I copy them to the frontend server?
3. Can I change the ownership of the files after I copied and untar the tarball? So far as I know only root can do this.
4. Is there any other solution or best practices copying files from the jenkins server to a remote server but with correct ownership?

I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks
CP

Comment: Why is it a "problem" to have the web server owned by apache but the content by www-deploy?

Comment: Yes, this is my problem. Isn't It insecure to run with this setup?

Comment: I am not a web security expert and there are plenty of resources on the web to secure a web server. In our org, we follow the practice of minimizing access to what's needed. We have many single purpose accounts. Control is restricted via file permissions and/or ACL. Nothing runs as root if it can be avoided. One account serves up the web server and has read-only access to the content. Another account(s) has read-write access only to the content and not the webserver. In fact the content is a location outside the webserver directory, in some cases on a volume mounted as read-only!

Comment: As for tarball, whatever id extracts is the owner (hamdy if you can't chown). You can set up so you can sudo chown as well. But you can achieve == in linux but having a user be member of secondary groups, tje group of the other user. Then set file perms to inherit group (g+s), then have a dir user rreadonly, group writeable only or similar mixes as needed.